# A better way to do a many to many query, but with range of values from one table?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Looking for the best way to make this more efficient.  I'm trying to create many to many queries but in this case I need to gather multiple values from categories table, and then find all the projects that contain those categories then get the projects that match full info from their table. (using a nested set with left right values for categories table).

1. Take in the ID of the category node and get left right values.

   ```
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `categories_main`'
   . ' WHERE `id`=:id';
   ```
2. Use the left right values found above to find all categories that have left right values within the range (all children categories)

   ```
   $sql = 'SELECT `id`'
   ```

   . ' FROM `categories_main`'
   . ' WHERE `lft` >= :lft AND `rgt` <= :rgt';
3. find project ID's in linking table that belong to one of the categories found above.

   ```
   $inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($category_ids), '?'));

   $sql = 'SELECT project_id, cat_id'
   ```

   . ' FROM project_sites_categories_main'
   . ' WHERE cat_id IN(' . $inQuery . ')';

4.And then I take the project ids and actually get the project full project from their table.

```
    $inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($project_ids), '?'));
    $sql = 'SELECT * '
. ' FROM project_sites'
. ' WHERE id IN(' . $inQuery . ')';
```

Any direction would be great. I've found some tutorials and threads pertaining to many to many,  but I cant seem to figure out how to make that work for a range of values from a table to get the linked files from the other.

thank you so much in advance for the help. I hope this is enough information.

Comment: maybe post this on the codereview site?

Comment: @Akintunde007 No, this is a feature request. Those are not welcome on Code Review. Once it works as intended, it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not much different from your query but I think using exists instead of in for not static values is better.

```
select * from project_sites  
    where id EXISTS  (select project_id from project_sites_categories_main 
                                    where cat_id EXISTS  (select id from categories_main 
                                                               where lft >= :lft and <= :rgt)
```

PS: if you want to performance improvment your query dont use `select *` just write columns what you need.